# field should start with 304050 in salesforce

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have a custom filed with number datatype and I have a requirement the the field should always start with 304050 and I have to write a condition that it must always contain 16 digits.

Is this posible?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried using validation rules?

Comment: I tried but i am not able to get it right

Comment: Ankita, you would paste your code here for better help.

Comment: NOT(REGEX(Card_Number__c, "\\D*?(\\d\\D*?){16}"))

This is working now .. now i have to make sure that it always starts with 304050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ashwini's answer is correct with small change......

```
OR 
( 
LEFT(TEXT(field__c),6) != '304050', 
LEN(TEXT(field__c)) != 16 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something similar like this in validation rule using three functions (OR, LEFT, LEN):

```
OR 
    (
      (LEFT(field__c,6) != '304050',
      LEN(field__c) != 16
    )
```

*Solution is for your hint purpose. may not be 100% correct.*

Comment: Thanks..this is working if i have a text field ..but i have a number field and i cannot risk user entering text after 304050